# Error message: "ensure that the target device screen is unlocked" when using emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, emulation

Anyone knows why I get the error message when debugging on emulator : "the application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed." while  Developing in Visual Studio 2010.

I've Googled it through and try the solution, but still not fixed my problem.
Btw, my solution type is SLXNA so, there are 3 projects in there, the main project, lib project, and libcontent project.

What I've tried :

1. Set the main project as the startup project
2. Checked the build and deploy check box for the main project and checked the build checkbox for the lib project
3. Change active solution platform to Windows phone
4. Rebuild solution

But it's still didn't fixed the problem

But when I debug it on device, it runs smoothly

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You did not say specifically, but have you registered on AppHub, paid $100, connected the Windows phone 7 and unlocked it such that you see the tiles on the home screen? Also, do you have the latest Zune software installed? Have you restarted your computer?

Comment: actually the error message shows up when i'm developing in emulator. the message didn't show up when i'm instead developing on device

Comment: so i tried to delete couple of pictures from the libcontent, and now i can develop again in the emulator. does the emulator have certain limit for the size of the project?

Comment: So you don't even have an actual Windows Phone 7 device when you are experiencing the issue?

Comment: Did you set target device to `Emulator`? Maybe, it unsuccessfully tried to deploy to device instead of emulator...

Comment: Compile it and look at the XAP file that gets created.  How big is it with the images included?

Comment: @Robaticus it's 61 MB(when it still error), but after i deleted some images, it's 51 MB and the program worked again

Comment: @Eugene I have actual windows phone device, but i'm curious as why i can't develop it in emulator

Comment: @ku6opr actually, i've set it to emulator, the programs even has installed to emulator, but when it run it shows "the application could not be launched for debugging. ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."

Comment: @bysreg - that is odd. You may want to try posting this on the AppHub forums to see if they have any insight.

Comment: Could just be a buggy install... I had this message pop up a couple of times, but I'd wiggle the cords and it'd go away. Are you running Visual Studio Express or a full-blown edition? You could try putting the latest SDK patches or wipe-out and re-install the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good news : i've solved this by simply installing the windows phone sdk 7.1.1

Answer (score 6):

- Make sure that the project you want to run is set a default Startup
  project
- Make sure that in dropdown on top you have selected "Windows    Phone
  Emulator", not "Windows Phone Device"
- And the most important    is: click on an arrow pointing down near
  the Debug/Release    configuration and open Configuration Manager... 
  Make sure that the    checkbox is checked in a column "Deploy" next
  to your project name.

Comment: as i said in the question, i've done this step but no results

Comment: What worked for me was to re-check the Configuration Manager. My project was already the start up project and I wanted to use the device, not the emulator. My problem was that my "active platform" changed when I started debuggin on an iPhone (I'm a xamarin user). When the active platform changed, so it changed the build/deploy profile on the Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In case some WP8 developers stumble upon this:

I've seen the exact same error message on VS 2012 with a WP8 app. However, it worked when I switched to **Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone** (comes with the SDK).